# Herkou pg_restore to a database that has changed

Tags: postgresql, heroku, pg-restore

I'm wondering what should I do if I'm using Heroku Postgres and I want to dump the data of an `App 1.0`, then I want to `pg_restore` the data to a new version of the app, `App 2.0`. The problem is that `App 2.0` has new fields and tables and the pg_restore [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgrestore.html) writes:

> ... will issue the commands necessary to reconstruct the database to
>   the state it was in at the time it was saved.

I don't want to reconstruct the database to the state it was on `App 1.0`, I only want to get the data and put it on the new database, the tables and fields I added should not conflict with the data in the dump file.

One option would be to `pg_restore` and "reconstruct the database to the state it was in at the time it was saved" and then run the migrations again. Is it the best way to go? there might be a better way, thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a `pg_dump --data-only` which will skip the table creation and only dump the data rows. Then when you restore, your data will go into existing tables. So you'll need to make sure that they already exist in the new database. I'm not sure offhand what will happen if the table definitions are different.

Alternatively, you could do a `pg_dump --table <table>` for only the tables you want to keep.